# Failed to print the result according to the priorities I set

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, web-scraping

I'm trying to create any logic so the script can print the result according to the priorities I set. In oppose to how I tried, the results are printed following the sequence.

To be more precise, I want to print the results as `E`, `D`, `B`, and `A`, regardless of how they appear in the list.

I've tried with:

```
items = ['A','B','D','E']

for item in items:
    if item=="E":
        print(item)
    elif item=="D":
        print(item)
    elif item=="B":
        print(item)
    elif item=="A":
        print(item)
```

Current output:

```
A
B
D
E
```

Expected output:

```
E
D
B
A
```

EDIT:

I created the demo above to get any suggestion so I can implement the same within the script below. The following script iterates through all the websites in the predefined list. From each of the sites, I wish to get the link associated with `contact` button. In case there is no contact button, I'm willing to go for the link connected to `about` button.

Here is how I have tried:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    "http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/",
    "https://www.richardsonproperties.com/",
    "https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/",
    "http://www.knowledgeplatform.com/",
    "http://www.singaporeenterpriseassociation.com/",
    "https://www2.deloitte.com/sg/en.html"
]

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'
}

for link in links:
    res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    target_link = ''
    for item in soup.select("a[href]"):
        if "contact" in item.text.lower():
            target_link = urljoin(link,item['href'])
            break

        elif "about" in item.text.lower():
            target_link = urljoin(link,item['href'])
            break

    print(target_link)
```

The "about" link appears frequently when I run the script, even though the "contact" link is available.

Comment: Don't loop, just do `if 'E' in items: print('E') if 'D' in items: print('D') ...`…?! Or do you want to *sort* the list into the specific order?

Comment: Please, check out the edit @deceze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prioritize `contact link` over `about link` in the following ways:

```
res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
target_link = None

for item in soup.select("a[href]"):
    if "contact" in item.text.lower():
        target_link = urljoin(link,item['href'])
        break

if target_link is None:
    for item in soup.select("a[href]"):
        if "about" in item.text.lower():
            target_link = urljoin(link,item['href'])
            break

print(target_link)
```

Comment: I'll let you know once I'm done testing on it.